# Memory efficiency in objects

Tags: javascript, object, mootools

Is either of these patterns more or less efficient than the other?

Pattern 1:

```
var jso = new Class({
   initialize: function () {
     // code
   },
   hiliteField: function () {
     // code
   }
});
```

Pattern 2:

```
var jso = new Class({
   initialize: function () {
     this.hiliteField = hiliteField.bind(this);
     // code  
   }
});
var hiliteField = function () {
  // code
}
```

Comment: Check http://www.aminutewithbrendan.com/pages/20110216

Comment: Thanks for the link!  It led me to this: http://jsperf.com/closure-vs-prototype-speed, which has given me a better idea how to realistically benchmark the concept.  I like the discussion, but I think they tend to use unrealistically simplistic objects for their tests.  I can reproduce the test using my actual objects, which have exponentially greater complexity, and have a real-world benchmark specific to my project.  Good times are had by all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having multiple methods that are external to the class and up the scope chain, as opposed to behind the class as 'namespaced' methods can't be better, imo.

Don't like pattern #2 for several reasons:

- manageability - having to bind a reference to each external function into the class is going to be hard to do.
- readability - having to indicate which function is being used by what class is going to be a task
- extendibility - because the functions are outside of the jso class prototype, classes that extend jso or use it as a mixin won't be able to access the external methods.

That being said, from a memory standpoint - just do a test but I would say, pattern 1 is likely to have a smaller overhead because it's defined once on the prototype and not in every instance individually.

Comment: Even if the memory footprint of #2 was smaller, it would be offset by the increased CPU usage of binding all those functions on each class instantiation. EDIT: I guess this comment should have gone in the question, not this answer :)

Answer (score 1):

Pattern 2 will use more memory! It's the basics of [prototypal inheritance](http://javascript.crockford.com/prototypal.html)

Why? In Pattern 1 every instance of `jso` will reference `jsoInstanceX.hiliteField` to `jso.prototype.hiliteField`. Read: `hiliteField` will not be a copy, it will only exist in `jso.prototype`.

In Pattern 2 you create a function wrapper each time you assign `hiliteField.bind(this);`. The additional memory is not much, but it's also slower, especially with impact on Class initialization.